# Ubuntu: XFCE: Is there a workaround for swiching to IntelliJ IDEA with wmctrl after IDEA removed "IntelliJ" from the `window title`?

Tags: xfce, wmctrl, intellij

I have shortcut keys setup that take the focus to a certain application in my Xubuntu setup.

So e.g.:
START+1 takes me to my main web browser window
START+2 takes me to my main Sublime window

START+3 used to take me to IntelliJ IDEA using this command set in `XFCE settings editor` under `xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts`:
`bash -c 'wmctrl -a "IntelliJ IDEA" || /opt/idea-IC-202.7660.26/bin/idea.sh'`

I haven't used IDEA for some time and now after upgrading I see that there is no `"IntelliJ IDEA"` in the title bar of the application any more - just the name of the project and optionally full path..

So my setup is broken..

Is there a way to fix it?
I am not that tough in Linux yet, but I was thinking if searching it in the process tree would help find that project name and path that in turn could be piped to `wmctrl` or is that even possible?

Food for thought.
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `xprop` to get the class of the window and then use that instead of the title, this shouldn't change any time soon.

You can run `xprop | grep -i class` from a terminal and then click on your Intellij IDEA window and it should print out the class in the terminal.

I have not used wmctrl, but I use the class or appid of a window in Sway to make keybinds to focus specific programs.

edit: a quick glance at the wmctrl man page shows that the `-x` argument may help you. "Include WM_CLASS in the window list or interpret  as the WM_CLASS name."

Comment: Thanks for help bdju!  
xprop yielded `WM_CLASS(STRING) = "jetbrains-idea-ce", "jetbrains-idea-ce"`  
but the command  
`bash -c 'wmctrl -a -x "jetbrains-idea-ce" || /opt/idea-IC-202.7660.26/bin/idea.sh'`  
Takes ~3 seconds which is not what I'm looking for as I constantly jump between windows copy-pasting stuff, I need <.5 seconds, in 3 seconds I can reach for the mouse and do a backflip ; )
Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry to hear it's so slow. I'm not really sure why that would be. I haven't got experience with wmctrl, but in i3 and Sway I can focus a window by its class in a fraction of a second.
I've heard you can run an alternative WM alongside xfce, so you could consider running i3 + xfce and using i3 for the window-focusing. Just a thought.

Comment: would you have an idea how to start debugging this kind of a thing?

Comment: I'm not sure. If it were me, I would start exploring other methods after finding out that way was slow for some reason. I found a plugin that lets you change the title. Could be worth a try, and then maybe your old method could work again. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9681-custom-title

Comment: this would have been a great lead if not the plugin was abandoned and not compatible with new IDEA versions : / `Plugin 'Custom Title' version 0.0.3 is incompatible with this installation` thanks a lot anyway!